# .NET Core 3 builds timeline?

Tags: azure-devops

I am trying to build .net core 3.1 project but seems like its not supported yet but we need to download sdk into the pipeline and then use it.

Is there some timeline when to expect .net core 3.x tasks to build projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there some timeline when to expect .net core 3.x tasks to build projects?

I am afraid there is no such timeline when to expect .net core 3.x tasks to build projects.

As we know, Updating a managed agent is a heavy workload. It will take a long time and resources. More often, the MS needs to shut down the server, re-update the image and deploy it to update the version of software. This will cause global users to be unable to use it during this period, so MS will not easily update the software version, especially when we can complete the corresponding requirements through the tasks provided by MS.

Just like MS replied:

> Right now, we don't have a great way for you to know when updates to
>   the images are coming. When we have the code available here, you can
>   watch the Releases for when we generate candidate environments, and
>   when we deploy new ones.

That is reason why MS provided the task [Use .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/tool/dotnet-core-tool-installer?view=azure-devops). In this case, we could use the latest .net core earlier.

You could check the document [hosted.md](https://github.com/actions/virtual-environments/blob/master/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#net-core) for the update info about the .net core version.

Besides, even if MS decides to update the software version, because the update time of the image is different in different regions, it will be difficult for MS to provide an accurate timeline for each region.

Therefore, I am afraid it difficult to give a timeline to expect .net core 3.x tasks to build projects.

Hope this helps.